# UIPageControl + UIScrollView inside UITableViewCell in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uiscrollview, xcode6, uipagecontrol

There're custom table view cells with horizontal scrolling and page control in Apple's Activity app. How to create similar ones in swift?

The only difference here is I need to have dynamic number of pages. Can I create one page (a number of labels and images on a scroll view) in story board and then clone and modify them as many times as I need in code? How do I do that?

I've found a few similar questions, but they're all old and none of them in swift.

Comment: Make a custom cell put all the content into a scroll view,use scroll view delegate,to snap to a page when a user scrolls,and put down a page control with an IBAction and do an animation when the user clicks on the animation